# how to replace values in sql

Tags: sql, asp.net

I WANT LIKE THIS IN THE ATTACHMENT

[image]

thanks

Comment: I want a lot of stuff too, but writing one small capitalized sentence and posting a vague image does not make that happen. Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For getting output what you need ,first table record you need to **de-concatenate**, i mean single rows record make multi rows record and then put inner join. then again you need to apply concatenation on result using stuff function in sql server.

Comment: SELECT * FROM dbo.Split(',', '1,2,3') , use like this for deconcatenat, hope you get idea to resolve the problem.

Comment: thanks for your answer but i need something to give it try i need solution to test it in my data base to see the result